# Loop through XML file and calculate the sum of values inside a particular XML tag

Tags: c#

Below is my XML file;

```
<DIMENSION>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>A</name>
      <STATUS>
        <name>Talk</name>
        <percentage>-1</percentage>
        <ID>CT</ID>
      </STATUS>
      <STATUS>
        <name>B</name>
        <percentage>-1</percentage>
        <ID>CN</ID>
      </STATUS>
      <STATUS>
        <name>none</name>
        <percentage>80</percentage>
        <ID>NONE</ID>
      </STATUS>
</DIMENSION>
<DIMENSION>
      <id>0</id>
      <name>C</name>
      <STATUS>
        <name>read</name>
        <percentage>-1</percentage>
        <ID>UR</ID>
      </STATUS>
      <STATUS>
        <name>D</name>
        <percentage>-1</percentage>
        <ID>DC</ID>
      </STATUS>
      <STATUS>
        <name>E</name>
        <percentage>-1</percentage>
        <ID>OR</ID>
      </STATUS>       
      <STATUS>
        <name>S</name>
        <percentage>-1</percentage>
        <ID>SA</ID>
      </STATUS>       
      <STATUS>
        <name>X</name>
        <percentage>95</percentage>
        <ID>CA</ID>
      </STATUS>
</DIMENSION>
```

I want to loop through the XML file and find the sum of percentage values inside each Dimension section of a particular id(id tag). For example for id 2 I want to sum all the percentage values. So my output should be 78. Similarly i want to loop through all the DIMENSION tags that contains an id tag and calculate the percentage. I am using XML linq and below is the code that I derived to. But my below code is giving me the overall percentage of all the dimension tags irrespective of the id tag but I want the sum of percentages of dimension tags with particular Id values. My first percentage output value is 78. My second percentage value output is 74. My third and fourth percentage output value is 78 as well.

```
public static void percentagecalculationallotmentDimension(string XMLpath, "DIMENSION", string "STATUS")
{
    try
    {
        byte[] preamble = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XMLpath + @"\filterSetsOut5.xml");
        foreach (XElement xmltag in doc.Descendants("DIMENSION"))
        {
            if (!xmltag.Element("id").Value.Equals("0"))
            {
                foreach (XElement xmltag1 in xmltag.Descendants("STATUS"))
                {
                    int sum = (from nd in doc.Descendants(subsection).Descendants("percentage")
                    select Int32.Parse(nd.Value)).Sum();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Logger.Instance.ErrorLog("Error while alloting percentage for" + mainsection + "" + subsection + "section due to" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting in your post - everything is much further over to the right than is required. We also don't need 171 lines of XML - just a *short* sample file, along with a short but *complete* program showing what you're trying to achieve would make this a much better question.

Comment: Will there definitely be a single Dimension tag per ID? It would help if your question asked about *one* situation: either summing the percentages for all tags, or just one tag, not both.

Comment: Are you the author of the xml document as well.  Can you make changes to the xml format?

Comment: There will be only single DIMENSION tag per id. My question is not the output for summing up the percentages for all tags, my question is summing up the percentage under every <id> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
var x = XElement.Parse(xml).Elements("DIMENSION");
List<int> sums = new List<int>();

foreach (var item in x)
{
    try
    {
        sums.Add(item.Elements("STATUS").Elements("percentage").Sum(e => int.Parse(e.Value)));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: what should i replace "xml" with. When I replace "xml" with absolute path of XML document. I get an error. " Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' to 'string'"

Comment: XDocument.Load(path).Elements("DIMENSION")

Comment: XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XMLpath + @"\filterSetsOut5.xml"); 
var x = XDocument.Load(doc).Elements("DIMENSION");
List<int> sums = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in x)
            {
                try
                {
                    sums.Add(item.Elements("STATUS").Elements("percentage").Sum(e => int.Parse(e.Value)));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' to 'string'.